# Powerapps: Dataverse plugin C# to check if column has been update

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, powerapps, dataverse

I would like to create a Powerapps C# plugin to check if the Dataverse table column "expired" has been updated then make a modification to another table based if it's expired.

Need help with writing the initial check if the column "expired" was modified or added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you don't want Power Automate?

[image: Dataverse trigger]

When you create a flow that triggers on update, it can check which column gets updated, and only if the rowfilter criteria is met, your flow continues to change other fields for example.

Maybe something to look into?

Answer (score 1):

The “filtering attribute” is available exactly for that purpose. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/best-practices/business-logic/include-filtering-attributes-plugin-registration?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#additional-information)

> Filtering attributes are a list of entity attributes that, when changed, cause the plug-in to execute. These attributes can be set when registering the plug-in using the Plug-in Registration tool. If no attributes are set, then the plug-in will execute every time an update message occurs.

[image]